# Regular expression needed for specific string in PHP

Tags: regex, string, validation

I need a regular expression to validate a string with the following conditions

1. String might contain any of  digits space + - () / .
   If string contain anything else then it should be invalid
2. If there is any + in the string then it should be at the beginning and there should at most                one + , otherwise it would be invalid, if there are more than one + then it is invalid
3. String should be 7 to 20 character long
4. It is not compulsory to have all these  digits space + - () / .
   But it is compulsory to contain at least 7 digit

Comment: So... what have you tried?

Comment: Why one regular expression? Some of the conditions you mention are clearly implementable without using regexes and in a more efficient way, even if this means writing more lines of code.

Comment: If you were looking for phone number validation see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are validating phone numbers with [E.164](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164) format. Phone number can contain many other format.  It can contain `.` too. Multiple spaces in a number is not uncommon.  So its better to format all the numbers to a common format and store that format in db. If that common format is wrong you can throw error.

I validate those phone numbers like this.

```
function validate_phone($phone){
    // replace anything non-digit and add + at beginning
    $e164 = "+". preg_replace('/\D+/', '', $phone);
    // check validity by length;
    return (strlen($e164)>6 && strlen($e164)<21);
}
```

Here I store `$e164` in Db if its valid.

Even after that you can not validate a phone number. A valid phone number format does not mean its a valid number. For this an sms or call is generated against the number and activation code is sent. Once the user inputs the code phone number is fully validated.

Comment: It does more than validating: it cleans up the input (without feedback to user), then validate the numbers. There are advantages and disadvantages to this method, though.

Comment: Could you provide the disadvantages. I am using this same method in an application which is in production already. We also validate phone by sending sms later.

Comment: Your method is permissive to the extreme - it doesn't care whether the original input contains garbage (binary data, letter, etc.) and just strip everything down to number. I **personally** think that total garbage should not be even processed. (I don't think the disadvantage really shows in this case).

Comment: When its phone number why do you need binary data or even letter?

Comment: The thing is that it considers the clean up version of previously obviously invalid input to be valid.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try ...

```
preg_match('/^(?=(?:.*\d){7})[+\d\s()\/\-\.][\d\s()\/\-\.]{6,19}$/', $text);
```

Breaking this down:

- We start with a positive look-ahead that requires a digit at least 7 times.
- Then we match all the valid characters, including the plus.
- Followed by matching all the valid characters without plus between 6 and 20 times.

Comment: Should i use preg_match? Could you show me with an example? I am totally new in regular expression. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: Missing `$` at the end, and you allow the string to have 21 characters.

Comment: This still allows multiple consecutive `-` or `.` - is this ok ?

For instance, `0000-000--` would match.  If not, we need to modify the regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one regex:

```
/^(?=(?:.*\d){7})[0-9 ()\/+-][0-9 ()\/-]{6,19}$/
```

However I would personally do something like:

```
/^[0-9 ()\/+-][0-9 ()\/-]{6,19}$/
```

And then strip any non-digit and see if the remaining string is 7 or longer.

Comment: /^[0-9 ()\/+-][0-9 ()\/-]{6,19}$/  this don't validate - but if my string contains - then it should be true. How can i do this? Thanks anyway for the answer

Answer (score 0):

A little more concise:

```
^\+?(?=(.*\d){7})[()/\d-]{7,19}$
```

'Course, why would you even use regular expressions?

```
function is_valid($string) {
    $digits = 0;
    $length = strlen($string);

    if($length < 7 || $length > 20) {
        return false;
    }

    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        if(ctype_digit($string[$i])) {
            $digits++;
        } elseif(strpos('+-() ', $string[$i]) === false && ($string[$i] !== '+' || $i !== 0)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return $digits >= 7;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't include the `+` in the length computation, so you won't permit a 20-character string without a `+`.

Comment: @MartinBaulig: Yes, I figured that adding a `+` probably shouldn’t change the maximum length, seeing as it’s optional. If I’m wrong... this is not the right one, then :)